# Calculate formula between integer $i$ and $j$

Tags: matrices

Background (actually I refers to AES shift row):

A and B are $4$ x $4$ matrices

```
A = |0 4 8 12 |
    |1 5 9 13 |
    |2 6 10 14|
    |3 7 11 15|

B = |0 4 8 12 |   // no shift
    |5 9 13 1 |   // shift 1 column to left
    |10 14 2 6|   // shift 2 columns to left
    |15 3 7 11|   // shift 3 columns to left
```

In $A$, when $i = 0 to 15$ in sequence

In $B$, $j$ equals to $0 ,5, 10, 15; 4, 9, 14, 3; 8, 13, 2, 7; 12, 1, 6, 11$

**Question:**

How to calculate the formula of function $f(i) = j$ that $f(0)=0, f(1)=5, f(2)=10$?

Comment: Can you rewrite the question using LaTeX? Also, explain what work you have done so far. I don't know what one formula of variable $0, ..., 16$ to present $j$ means.

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for a formula for a function $f$ where $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=5$, $f(2)=10$ and so on down the list.

Comment: I see, inside A $f(0,0) = 0, f(1,0)  = 1, f(2,0)  = 2, f(3,0)  = 3, f(0,1) = 4, f(1,1) = 5 ...$ so moving down a row adds 1 and moving right a column adds 4. Inside $B$, $f(0,0) = 0, f(1,0)  = 5, f(2,0)  = 10, f(3,0)  = 15, f(0,1) = 4, f(1,1) = 9 ...$ so it must be some sort of shifting function.

Comment: According to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0,+5,+10,+15,+4,+9,+14,+3,+8,+13,+2,+7+... it would be a(n + 3) = a(n) - 1 (for all n>=1).

Comment: @Axion004: is it possible to calculate the formula use operators (+, -, *, /, reminder...)?

Comment: Please use MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(i)& = \begin{cases}
i & \text{ if } i \mod 4 = 0\\
(i + 4) \mod 16 & \text{ if } i \mod 4 = 1\\
(i +8)  \mod 16& \text{ if } i \mod 4 = 2\\
(i +12) \mod 16 & \text{ if } i \mod 4 = 3
\end{cases}\\
& = (i+4(i \mod 4)) \mod 16.
\end{align}

Here $ \mod $ refers to reminder.